# How would I open two programs in Python using subprocess simulataneously without waiting for the other process to finish?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, simultaneous

I'm attempting to run a GUI and some driver code simulataneously. Both are initiated after successful login and the driver code contains code that updates a database the GUI code reads, I want both to be run simultaneously without the GUI code waiting for the driver code to finish or vice versa.

```py
subprocess.call(["pypy3", "gui-main-staff.py"])
subprocess.call(["pypy3", "driver.py"]))
```

I've tried using `multiprocessing` but I couldn't get both to execute separately. Possibly I used it wrong?

Comment: Hi, Nail. Can you show us an example of the expected result?